# Lua Logitech mouse script error have to replace math.pow

Tags: lua

I am kind of lost and have no knowledge how to fix this code , a friend of my provided me a Lua script for a recoil control.

from what I understood i need to replace this string 326 with x^y

this is the pastebin if anyone willing to help :https://pastebin.com/MMD42d4s

```
return 0.002 * math.pow(10, unconvertedSens / 50)
```

Comment: Replace `math.pow(10, unconvertedSens / 50)` with `10^(unconvertedSens/50)`

Answer (score 0):

From the [Lua 5.3 Reference Manual 8.2 Changes in the Libraries](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#8.2):

> The following functions were deprecated in the mathematical library:
> atan2, cosh, sinh, tanh, pow, frexp, and ldexp. **You can replace
> math.pow(x,y) with x^y**; you can replace math.atan2 with math.atan, which now accepts one or two arguments; you can replace math.ldexp(x,exp) with x * 2.0^exp. For the other operations, you can either use an external library or implement them in Lua.

So change your code to `return 0.002 * 10^(unconvertedSens / 50)`

Comment: I did change that but im getting another syntax error from string above it :  function convert_sens(unconvertedSens)

Comment: @dolmaftw post a new question, post the error message and the related code.